# Mr Doobs cloud example: making an airplane fly trough clouds

Tags: three.js

I've taken a look at Mr Doob's example of animated clouds.
I already had an example of an airplane in Threejs.

Now, I want to make the plane fly trough the clouds... Is there anyone who has any idea how to get this done?

The clouds are there, The plane is there... now I need to have have plane in the foreground, and the clouds animating over the plane ;-).

Any help is much appreciated.
[image]
[image]
I found a partial solution using 2 scenes, but the clouds aren't (yet) animating over the plane...

Source:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nm9fbxx2gc3k3rb/Jet.zip?dl=0

just run: node install  and bower install
afterwards, in your terminal: gulp serve
and the project should run.

Comment: it's much better if you can post live examples instead of zip files

Comment: I Will try to set something up later today/tomorrow.

Comment: I can't create a JSFiddle because I needs to load assets like textures and json's etc... d

Comment: yes sorry to hear that.i ran your code but i don't see any jet?

Comment: which version of Three are you using? Did you see any errors in the console?

Comment: i used the same one in your zip file

Comment: I uploaded my complete project setup (without nodemodules and bower components) : https://www.dropbox.com/s/nm9fbxx2gc3k3rb/Jet.zip?dl=0
Just run npm install and bower install. After that you can start the server by running gulp serve in the terminal.

Thanks for looking into it so far!